# What do you call an authority who issues certifications?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is the correct term given to an entity/body who have the authority to issue certifications in a field?

The obvious thing that comes to mind is "Certification Authority (CA)", however when I Google this term all I find are references to CAs in the context of cryptography.

For example.. I complete an online course in some subject, let's just say Amazon's AWS Cloud Architect or something. In this case, Amazon are the authority providing a certification. Does that make them... a certificate authority?

Comment: There isn't a single term.  The term used is generally specified/implied by the rules and regulations that lay out the need for certification.

Comment: Allowing 'phrase requests' may help answer your question.

Comment: They're often called "Certification **boards**", in the context of a person acquiring certification after passing an exam, for example, but as @HotLicks says there's no consistent word for this.

Comment: An authority that or which issues certificates is generally know as a certificating authority. If the nature of the particular certificates matters, that might change everything

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Using the Amazon example, that company vests the authority to issue a certificate in themselves. **Amazon is the certificating authority**.  As mentioned in comments, other authorities call themselves boards etc.  In the U.S. many boards certify certify doctors and other aspects of healthcare.

https://aws.amazon.com/certification/certification-agreement/

certify:  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/certification

Colleges certify you when granting you a degree.

the Red Cross among many others can certify you to perform basic CPR.

Many certificates are necessarily renewable ... CPR  Some a lifetime ... the college degree.

Comment: "certificating" ? Really?  The cambridge.org link has "certification authority" as the next word.  The other plausible alternative is "certifying authority" , but "certificating" seems wrong to my BrE ears.

Comment: @MartinBonner English. Verb. Certificating - present participle of certificate. But certifying is good too. Thank-you.

Comment: But surely the verb corresponding to the noun certificate is "certify"?

Answer (score 1):

- For official documents that are *issued* (e.g. birth certificates or visas, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travel_visa)) you could use **issuing authority** (or, more general, **issuing body**)
- For diplomas that are *awarded*, [this page](http://cdn.prospects.ac.uk/pdf/Advice%20and%20Guidance%20on%20Degree%20Fraud%20for%20HE%20Providers.pdf) speaks of **awarding body**
- although **issuer** seems to be mostly used in finance, it is also used for the body issuing a *permit* (e.g. allowing work where Safety is an issue)

Answer (score 0):

What about a [licenser?](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/licenser) It’s not elaborate but it is eloquent.

The definition of *license* (verb) is:

> 1a: to issue a license to
>
> 1b: to permit or authorize especially by formal license
>
> 2: to give permission or consent to; allow.

(Definitions from Merriam-Webster.)

So a “licenser” would mean “someone who licenses.”